# How can I make a bool array that saves the positions of numbers that are larger than 0 in a 2D array?

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures

I'm creating an algorithm that solves the Sudoku puzzle, but one of the requirements is that I have to create a bool array that locks the initial positions of any assigned number (In this case, any number that isn't 0) so that when the algorithm runs, it doesn't change the numbers that are "locked"

basically, the array below is the "puzzle" itself, I need to create a 2D bool array that saves the positions of the initially provided numbers so that the algorithm cannot change them later on when it runs

here's the code for the puzzle itself and the data structure:

```
#define N 9
typedef struct Coordinates
{

    int row;
    int column;

};

int sudokuArray[N][N] = {
            {0,0,0,6,0,0,4,0,0},
            {7,0,0,0,0,3,6,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,9,1,0,8,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,5,0,1,8,0,0,0,3},
            {0,0,0,3,0,6,0,4,5},
            {0,4,0,2,0,0,0,6,0},
            {9,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,2,0,0,0,0,1,0,0}
    };
```

Comment: What is your problem exactly? Defining this 2D array, or calculating its values?

Comment: That's the "puzzle" itself, I need to create a 2D bool array that saves the positions of the initially provided numbers so that the algorithm cannot change them later on when it runs

Comment: I was mentionning the new array, i.e. something like  `bool sudoinput[N][N]`

Comment: I'm not sure how to initialize it and how to save the "coordinates" of each assigned number, I edited the post a little bit its clearer now, I hope

Comment: Sorry, it is still not very clear. You may declare the new array as above, and then use two `for` loops... `sudoinput[i][j] = sudokuArray[i][j] > 0;`

Comment: Check the IsSafe() function. It might be what you need: 
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sudoku-backtracking-7/

Comment: The question is tagged C++, but the code is very much C. The `typedef` is completely redundant in C++, and we'd use `const int N=9;` for type-safety.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something a little bit less memory efficient but faster:

Instead of having an array of values, store array of structures of values and bool that tells if given position is mutable.

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <array>

// Prefer constexpr to macros
constexpr uint32_t size = 9;

struct sudoku_field
{
    uint8_t value;
    bool is_mutable;
};

std::array<std::array<sudoku_field, size>, size> sudoku_board
{
    { {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {6, 1}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {4, 1}, {0, 0}, {0, 0} },
    { {7, 1}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {3, 1}, {6, 1}, {0, 0}, {0, 0} },
    ...
}
```

This approach will provide constant lookup time when you need to test if field should be mutable.

---

Your approach would require a vector of positions, where every entry in that vector is immutable.

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct coordinates
{
    int8_t row;
    int8_t column;
};

std::vector<coordinates> immutable_positions;

// And this would be a test funciton
bool is_immutable(int8_t row, int8_t column)
{
    auto res = std::find(std::begin(immutable_positions), 
        std::end(immutable_positions), 
        coordinates{row, column});
    return res == std::end(immutable_positions);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the exact same thing that you did for the sudoko puzzle.
Another option is to programmatically find which numbers are non-zero.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < ROW_SIZE; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < ROW_SIZE; ++j)
        {
            boolArray[i][j] = (sudokuArray[i][j] > 0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think he wants to use that array for an algorithm and fill it with data. If that's the case he will need to make a copy of it to allow testing for immutable elements.